# Different lines that run on top of each other show as different lines

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, offset, parallel-lines

Imagine I have some bus lines each with a different colour, and sometimes the different bus lines run on the same road, but I don't want one of them to disappear.

Is it possible to make them show as parallel like in the picture?

[image]

If I just simply draw the lines in parallel to each other, they will change appearance a lot as a zoom in or out and I would not have a consistent width between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a property "offset" to each line segment, draw the lines on top of each others and then apply an `offset` based on the recorded value.

This way, the offset can be maintained as you zoom in or out, and you have more flexibility than a fully automated solution to make it look good.

In the example below, the same line was copy-pasted 5 times, with a field named `offset` having the values `-2, -1, 0 , 1, 2`.

To the right of the `offset` setting, click the little epsilon symbol, choose `edit` and just write the field name (here, `offset`) and eventually a multiplier. Make sure the unit remains `millimeters` or `pixels` but **not** `map units`

[image]

Comment: What if the lines are only next to each other in a small segment of the road? What if they are separate then connect at one road and then separate again? I wouldn't want the offset to apply to the whole line. Or do I just have to make a separate line for this part?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by _add a property "offset" to each line segment_, so the same bus line can have various offset along its route (maybe start with an offset to the left (negative), then it is by itself on a street with an offset of 0 and join a main collector street with an offset to the right (positive))

Comment: Will each line segment need to be split up as multiple attributes?

Comment: I have not been able to find the tool that allows this offset.

Comment: @VictorNielsen it is in the layer styling options